# Proving the statement using induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Show that every expression of form $x^n + y^n , n \geq 1$, $n \in N$ can be always written as a polynomial in $x+y,xy$ , i.e. $x^n + y^n = Q(x+y,xy)$ where $Q$ is a polynomial in two variables . For example $x^2+y^2 = (x+y)^2 -2xy$ so polynomial is $x^2 - 2y = Q(x,y)$ .

> I was curious to show this by induction , base case would be n=1 for which its obv true . I assume now the induction hypothesis that its true for $x^k + y^k = Q(x+y,xy)$ for some $k \geq 1$ but i was not able to progress after that to prove its true for k+1 too since i was not able to relate $x^k+y^k$ with $x^{k+1} + y^{k+1}$

Comment: Note $x^{k+1} + y^{k+1} = (x + y)(x^k + y^k) - xy(x^{k-1} + y^{k-1})$.

Comment: So we need to check base cases for n= 1 and 2 both ? And then say its hold true for k and k-1 so inductively its true for k+1 ? @JohnOmielan

Comment: Yes, you have it (in case you didn't know, [strong induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction) is what is used when need to include multiple previous values, i.e., $k$ and $k-1$ in your case, in the inductive step)! You should consider answering your own question with the details of what you wrote in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^k + y^k = (x + y)^k + A \implies \color{blue}{x^k} = \color{blue}{(x + y)^k + A - y^k} \iff \color{green}{y^k} = \color{green}{(x + y)^k + A - x^k}$

Hence,

\begin{align}
x^{k+1} + y^{k+1} = x\cdot \color{blue}{x^k} + y\cdot \color{green}{y^k} &= x\left(\color{blue}{(x + y)^k + A - y^k}\right) + y\left(\color{green}{(x + y)^k + A - x^k}\right)\\
&=x(x+y)^k \color{grey}{+ x(A - y^k)} + y(x+y)^k \color{grey}{+ y(A - x^k)}\\
& = (x+y)(x + y)^k \color{grey}{+ x(A - y^k) + y(A - x^k)}\\
& = (x + y)^{k+1} \color{grey}{+ x(A - y^k) + y(A - x^k)}
\end{align}